# Netbeans error code 1?

Tags: java, netbeans, mobile

I want to try developing a mobile programme.
But when I run project as Java application, the project don't compile.
The Netbeans output like this:
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
Error code : "Execution failed with error code 1."
in:"../build-impl.xml:898"
How I fix it ?

Comment: Well there is a problem in your (NetBeans) build script. Sounds like it might be a path issue. Maybe NetBeans doesn't find the VM executable. Have a look at the build-impl.xml Ant file line 898 and see what it says there.

Comment: thanks it's resolved.
With adding a new  the emulator platform but the same content folder; like Java ME SDK 3.0 ,and the new one Java ME SDK 3.0 local.
I guessed that there was conflicted with Java ME Platform SDK.

Comment: hi i have windows 7 64 bit and i had this problem  "Execution failed with error code 1"
so i unistalled my netbeans and sdk 3 64 bit and instead i installed sdk 3 32 bit and netbeans again and my problem solved.for java me sdk 3 64 bit dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks it's resolved.
With adding a new  the emulator platform but the same content folder; like Java ME SDK 3.0 ,and the new one Java ME SDK 3.0 local.
I guessed that there was conflicted with Java ME Platform SDK.